# Haskell Help -- Calculating Mean of A List

Tags: haskell

I am struggling with this. And this is what I have attempted

```
mean :: [Float] -> Float
mean list = (sum list) / (fromInt (length list))
```

I am getting an error for `fromInt`. I have no idea why this is happening your help is much appreciated.

The error I get is : Not in scope: `fromInt'

And I can't use the recursive method.

If you have any tips and websites please do let me know

Thank You Very Much

Comment: You should tell us what the error message is.

Comment: You should copy and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: Not in scope: `fromInt'

Comment: @SohailButt The function you want to use is called [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html).

Comment: I am getting an error Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : meanr
*** Type           : [Float] -> Int
*** Does not match : [Float] -> Float

Answer (score 3):

You are using `fromInt` that doesn't exist and that's the error. For a short solution to the problem go to the end of this.

Let me start by saying that the reason why you need that `fromInt` (or a replacer, considering that's wrong) is because the `/` function exists on `Fractional` types. You can see it on `GHCI`:

```
Prelude> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a

Prelude> :t length
length :: [a] -> Int
```

The output of `length list` is and `Int` and `Int` is not a `Fractional`. You can check it from GHCI with `:i` that gives you also the instances of a type class:

```
Prelude> :i Fractional
class Num a => Fractional a where
  (/) :: a -> a -> a
  recip :: a -> a
  fromRational :: Rational -> a
      -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

So no, `Int` is not an instance of `Fractional`, only `Float` and `Double` are `Fractional`, and thus you cannot use `/`. You need to convert the output of `length list` to `Fractional` and my guess is that you were trying to use `fromIntegral`, that converts from an `Integral` to a `Num`, and you accidentally wrote `fromInt`.

I think this because `fromIntegral` is a type conversion function that "does what you need":

```
Prelude> :t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

the output of `length list`, is an `Int` that is `Integral`:

```
Prelude> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  -- [...]
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
```

and both `Float` and `Double`, that are `Fractional` and thus support `/`, are `Num`:

```
Prelude> :i Num
class Num a where
  -- [...]
instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float
```

so by using it you can convert an `Int` to a `Fractional` type and make your function compile:

```
mean :: [Float] -> Float
mean list = sum list / fromIntegral (length list)
```

For a reference on how numeric types conversions work in Haskell, have a look at [Converting Numbers](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers) of [Haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org).

Answer (score 1):

The error saying something is "not in scope" simply means that you've used a name that doesn't mean anything in a particular place. In this case, it is because you wrote `fromInt`, and there is no such function available. In some cases, you may have to import a certain module in order to bring something into scope. For example, to use the `inits` function, you would have to import `Data.List`, and to use the `Seq` type you would have to import `Data.Sequence`.

A bit more subtly, you can't use a *local* variable outside its scope:

```
y = let x = 3 in x*5
z = x + 4   -- Error: x is not in scope
```

Although there is an `x` somewhere in the module, it's only in scope within the `let` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to calculate means

Let's define a function that accept list of number and return double

```
mean :: [Double] -> Double
mean (x) = (x1)
    where x1 = sum x / fromIntegral (length x)

main = do 
   print( mean [1..10])
```